# MSMQ + WCF, IIS7 - Messages are being journaled, but never hitting the service

Tags: wcf, iis-7, msmq

Standard set up I think. I've followed: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx mainly, but used other sources as needed.

So far here is what happens:

1. Client sends a message
2. I see the message in the Journal Messages for the appropriate queue
3. Service never seems to be called. I have a ton of logging that would output logs on service called and / or errors in the service method.

I have shut down the service and the message still ends up in the Journal Messages - not sure why that is.

Queue: bretrace/bretraceservice.svc (anonymous access, with full permissions granted)

Client Web.config

```
<netMsmqBinding>
    <binding name="MsmqBreTrace" receiveErrorHandling="Move">
        <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
</netMsmqBinding>

<endpoint address="net.msmq://wcfserver/private/bretrace/bretraceservice.svc" binding="netMsmqBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="MsmqBreTrace" name="MsmqBreTraceService"
    contract="C.BusinessRuleController.Services.BoschProxy.Trace.IQueuingTraceContract"/>
```

Service Web.config

```
<bindings>
    <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="MsmqBreTraceReader" receiveErrorHandling="Move">
            <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
    </netMsmqBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
    <service name="C.BusinessRuleController.Services.QR.BreTraceService">
        <endpoint address=""
            binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="MsmqBreTraceReader"
            contract="C.BusinessRuleController.Services.BoschProxy.Trace.IQueuingTraceContract" />
    </service>
</services>
```

I have also activated system.diagnostics, and it seems to be calling the service, under activity I see:

- "Process Action: 'http://tempuri.org/IQueuingTraceContract/LogTrace'." **I'm not sure if the tempuri.org is a problem or not?**
- "Execute C.BusinessRuleController..." as another activity.

Comment: Have you enabled end to end tracing? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730882.aspx

Comment: I have enabled it - but I honestly have trouble making heads or tails of it. I have 3 events - Message came over network (event id 4) Message put into queue (event id 1), and Message Received (event id 2). I can't see where this is showing what service is receiving the message

Comment: If you have three events per message this would normally indicate that everything is fine. Have you thought about using transactional queues?

Comment: @hugh They are in a transactional queue. I've got all kinds of logging in the service method that should be receiving the message and nothing at all gets logged.

Comment: What about WCF tracing on the server? The only thing I can think is wrong is that you are getting some kind of serialization/formatting issue when you receive the message. Also I notice you are using netMsmqBinding. I assume therefore that your client is also WCF?

Comment: Corret client is WCF. Using EndToEnd it looks like in the last day errors have been turning up - "MsmqActiviation service cannot discover queues". We are on a domain, so I'm not sure the issue here, but that is providing more search queries to track down the issue. I'll post an update shortly

Comment: I did, but I have to think about to what I did to solve it. I'm pretty sure I was missing a "checkmark" next to a variety of things you are supposed to do to get this setup working

Comment: Shame you can't remember - alot of folks probably have the same issue and would benefit from your experience as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things solved this problem for me:

First, I had to set security mode='transactional' in the bindings

```
<netMsmqBinding>
    <binding name="MsmqBreTrace" receiveErrorHandling="Move">
        <security mode="Transactional" />
    </binding>
</netMsmqBinding>
```

Second, I had to installed MSMQ Active Directory Integration - I didn't have to actually enable it, but it had to be installed even when it wasn't used. This was what threw me the most, I didn't want AD Integration, so I figured I didn't need it. Turns out I was wrong.